# htaccess Rewrite Rule Exception

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ template.php?user_id=$1&slide=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So when I go to **www.mydomain.com/user/7/1** it is working, and pulling from **www.mydomain.com/template.php?user_id=7&slide=1**

Now my question is, how do I get the slide variable to be optional.  I want it to work if someone will type in **/user/7/**.

In my template.php file I have:

```
if(!$current_slide) {
    header("Location: user/".$user_id."/1");
}
```

So if I manually go to template.php?user_id=1 it will automatically redirect to /user/7/1/  which is good, it works.  But I need to modify my htaccess file so if someone types in /user/7/ it will redirect to /7/1/

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?([0-9]*)/?$ template.php?user_id=$1&slide=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Except when I go to /user/7 (no trailing slash) it won't work. only when I have a slash at the end.  Any way to force that slash or fix that?